# <aside> tag blocking web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I have been trying to scrape a website that shows every football match that will be played on a specific field. The site is dynamic and I have tried several things to conquer my problem. I tried to use the requests_html library and it renders every HTML element until it gets to `<aside>` tag. After that, it just renders "none". Can `<aside>` tag prevent web scraping or is my code otherwise flawed?

This is the code I tried to use.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = "https://tulospalvelu.palloliitto.fi/location/598/fixtures"

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=1)

fixtures = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="scrolldiv"]/main/div/aside', first=True)

print(fixtures)
```

```
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I use a different xpath that isn't inside the `<aside>` tag it renders the element properly:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = "https://tulospalvelu.palloliitto.fi/location/598/fixtures"

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=1)

fixtures = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="scrolldiv"]/main/div', first=True)

print(fixtures)
```

```
<Element 'div' class=('v-main__wrap',)>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is there something I can do to avoid this issue?

Comment: try to remove `first=True`

Comment: Now it just prints `[]   Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: Not quite sure how you want me to use that in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data into panda's dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = 'https://spl.torneopal.net/taso/rest/getMatches?start_date=2022-01-01&venue_location_id=598'
headers = {'Accept': 'json/df8e84j9xtdz269euy3h'}

data = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['matches'])

print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
  match_id match_number match_report match_external_id age_group aggregate_match competition_id       competition_name competition_result_service_name competition_logo competition_status competition_officiality season_id organiser organiser_private category_id       category_name                                              category_logo category_logo_dark_bg category_group category_group_name category_group_name_en category_live calculate_points season_order group_id  group_name phase_number phase_name      group_type alternative_groups match_type round_id round_name round_date_begin round_date_end round_team_id round_club_id round_club_name stage stage_name standings_name        date      time reschedule time_reservation_start  time_end        time_zone time_zone_offset sunset club_A_id            club_A_name club_A_abbrevation club_A_www                                          club_A_crest team_A_id       team_A_name team_A_abbrevation team_A_description team_A_description_en team_A_www club_A_distance team_A_home_venue_id team_A_primary_category_id club_B_id                 club_B_name club_B_abbrevation club_B_www club_B_distance                                         club_B_crest team_B_id  team_B_name team_B_abbrevation team_B_description team_B_description_en team_B_www team_B_home_venue_id team_B_primary_category_id statistics_level  status forfeit_A forfeit_B disqualify_A disqualify_B winner winner_id  walkover fs_A fs_B hts_A hts_B ns_A ns_B es_A es_B ps_A ps_B suspensions_A suspensions_B suspensions_officials_A suspensions_officials_B best_of_match best_of_count can_start_live lineups_filled best_of_sequence track_scorers track_assists starting_players  sport_id match_report_exists p1_start_team p1_start_time p1_end_time p1_duration p1s_A p1s_B p1_winner p2_start_team p2_start_time p2_end_time p2_duration p2s_A p2s_B p2_winner p3_start_team p3_start_time p3_end_time p3_duration p3s_A p3s_B p3_winner p4_start_team p4_start_time p4_end_time p4_duration p4s_A p4s_B p4_winner p5_start_team p5_start_time p5_end_time p5_duration p5s_A p5s_B p5_winner position_name players_aside serve_order players_substitutes substitutions max_fouls max_timeouts connected_matches referee_1_id            referee_1_name referee_1_player_id referee_2_id referee_2_name referee_2_player_id assistant_referee_1_id assistant_referee_1_name assistant_referee_1_player_id assistant_referee_2_id assistant_referee_2_name assistant_referee_2_player_id referee_1_join referee_2_join assistant_referee_1_join assistant_referee_2_join venue_id    venue_name venue_name_competition venue_city_name venue_city_id venue_area_id venue_referee_club_id   venue_area_name venue_location_id venue_location_name venue_suburb_name attendance report_attendance referee_classification assistant_referee_classification report_result playing_time_min period_count win_period_count period_count_fixed period_min extra_period_count extra_period_min ps_count live_period live_time live_time_mmss live_minutes live_A live_B live_ps_A live_ps_B live_timeouts_A live_timeouts_B live_timeout_skip_A live_timeout_skip_B live_serve_team live_fouls_A live_fouls_B     live_timer_start live_timer_start_time live_timer_on temperature weather stream_url ticket_url stream stream_media stream_media_name stream_img tv notice result_notice stamp fourth_official_id fourth_official_name fourth_official_player_id assign_fourth_official delegate_1_id delegate_1_name assign_delegate_1 delegate_2_id delegate_2_name assign_delegate_2   timestamp
0  2331269           92                           1952         M                        spljp22    SPL Jalkapallo 2022                                                            archived                official      2022       spl                 0         MSC  Miesten Suomen Cup  https://cdn.torneopal.net/img/palloliitto/spl/MSCblue.png                                    1              Miehet                                    1                1           66        7  1. Kierros            9             knockout_final                 []     single        4     Kori 4       2022-01-29     2022-03-09                                              alku                            2022-02-20  12:00:00          0               12:00:00  14:00:00  Europe/Helsinki            +0200  17:24       156  Koivukylän Palloseura              KoiPS              https://cdn.torneopal.net/logo/palloliitto/156x.png    130806      KoiPS/Dynamo                                 G/141          KoiPS/Dynamo                                                                         M5       151                   Kultsu FC          Kultsu FC                             https://cdn.torneopal.net/logo/palloliitto/151x.png     60503    Kultsu FC                                 G/142             Kultsu FC                            2788                         M3                   Played                                                 Away     60503         0    1    6     0     3                                                                                                                       0                                                            0             1                              1  football                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 16014              Sirviö Ville                                                                                      17329          Sorvanto Mikael                                                17586             Nassar Saleh                                                                                                                    600  Tikkurila TN                                 Vantaa            92           116                   ETE  Pääkaupunkiseutu               598           Tikkurila                           20                                       M2                               M2             0              120            2                2                  0         45                                            5          -1     00:00                                                                                                                                                                                  0000-00-00 00:00:00              00:00:00             0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1682855815
1  2353548           10                           8519         M                        spljp22    SPL Jalkapallo 2022                                                            archived                official      2022       spl                 0         MSC  Miesten Suomen Cup  https://cdn.torneopal.net/img/palloliitto/spl/MSCblue.png                                    1              Miehet                                    1                1           66        4      Tasaus           10             knockout_final                 []     single        2     Kori 2       2022-01-29     2022-02-20                                              alku                            2022-02-20  20:00:00          0               20:00:00  22:00:00  Europe/Helsinki            +0200  17:24      5176       Nikinmäki United   Nikinmäki United             https://cdn.torneopal.net/logo/palloliitto/5176x.png    183596  Nikinmäki United                             Tasaus/19      Nikinmäki United                                            2508                         M5        34              Esbo Bollklubb                EBK                              https://cdn.torneopal.net/logo/palloliitto/34x.png     63806  EBK/Reservi                             Tasaus/20           EBK/Reservi                             221                         M5                   Played                                                 Away     63806         0    0    3     0     1                                                                                                                       0                                                            0             1                              1  football                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 12425            Karttunen Jani                                                                                      12535             Kallio Sampo                                                15586          Selvitys pyyntö                                                                                                                    600  Tikkurila TN                                 Vantaa            92           116                   ETE  Pääkaupunkiseutu               598           Tikkurila                            0                                       M2                               M2             0              120            2                2                  0         45                                            5          -1     00:00                                                                                                                                                                                  0000-00-00 00:00:00              00:00:00             0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1682855815
2  2331204           54                           1887         M                        spljp22    SPL Jalkapallo 2022                                                            archived                official      2022       spl                 0         MSC  Miesten Suomen Cup  https://cdn.torneopal.net/img/palloliitto/spl/MSCblue.png                                    1              Miehet                                    1                1           66        7  1. Kierros            9             knockout_final                 []     single        2     Kori 2       2022-01-29     2022-03-09                                              alku                            2022-03-11  20:05:00          0               20:05:00  22:05:00  Europe/Helsinki            +0200  18:13       219               FC Korso           FC Korso              https://cdn.torneopal.net/logo/palloliitto/219x.png     63417   FC Korso/United                                  G/55       FC Korso/United                                             568                         M5       190  Suurmetsän Urheilijat SUMU               SUMU                             https://cdn.torneopal.net/logo/palloliitto/190x.png     53539     SUMU/sob                                  G/56              SUMU/sob                             368                         M4                   Played                                                 Away     53539         0    0    2                                                                                                                                   0                                                            0             1                              1  football                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 10497             Juvonen Elias                                                                                      12468              Juntto Joni                                                15748           Lahtonen Janne                                                                                                                    600  Tikkurila TN                                 Vantaa            92           116                   ETE  Pääkaupunkiseutu               598           Tikkurila                            0                                       M2                               M2             0              120            2                2                  0         45                                            5          -1     00:00                                                                                                                                                                                  0000-00-00 00:00:00              00:00:00             0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1682855815
3  2355504         9405                                      P14                        etejp22  Etelä Jalkapallo 2022                                                            archived                official      2022  spletela                 0        P141         P14 Ykkönen                                                                                               3               Pojat                                    1                1          246        1       Kevät            5   Tammikuu     group_stage                 []     single        1                  2022-03-19     2022-03-20                                              alku                            2022-03-20  13:10:00          0               13:10:00  14:40:00  Europe/Helsinki            +0200  18:35       156  Koivukylän Palloseura              KoiPS              https://cdn.torneopal.net/logo/palloliitto/156x.png    158370             KoiPS                               Kevät/4                 KoiPS                                                                       P152       162        Hyvinkään Palloseura               HyPS                             https://cdn.torneopal.net/logo/palloliitto/162x.png    170718         HyPS                               Kevät/8                  HyPS                             977                       P141                   Played                                                 Away    170718         0    1    2     1     1                                                                                                                       0                                                            0             1                              0  football                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 18163  Saarela DANIEL CHRISTIAN                                                                                      20799            Mattsson Rene                                                16012            Heino Viljami                                                                                                                    600  Tikkurila TN                                 Vantaa            92           116                   ETE  Pääkaupunkiseutu               598           Tikkurila                            0                                       P7                               P7             1               90            2                2                  0         40                                                       -1     00:00                                                                                                                                                                                  0000-00-00 00:00:00              00:00:00             0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1682855815
4  2318289         3390                                      P14                        etejp22  Etelä Jalkapallo 2022                                                            archived                official      2022  spletela                 0       P14LE     P14 Liiga Etelä                                                                                               3               Pojat                                    1                1          238        1           1            3    Lokakuu     group_stage                 []     single        2                  2022-03-26     2022-03-26                                              alku                            2022-03-26  10:30:00          0               10:30:00  12:00:00  Europe/Helsinki            +0200  18:50        59  Tikkurilan Palloseura               TiPS               https://cdn.torneopal.net/logo/palloliitto/59x.png    157198              TiPS                                   1/9                  TiPS                                                                      P15LE        63    Pallokerho Keski-Uusimaa               PKKU                              https://cdn.torneopal.net/logo/palloliitto/63x.png    168477         PKKU                                   1/1                  PKKU                             561                      P15LE                   Played                                                 Away    168477         0    1    2     0     1                                                                                                                       0                                                            0             1                              0  football                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 12989             Vanninen Arto                                                                                      18332             Kuopio Juuso                                                12838            Raumala Petri                                                                                                                    600  Tikkurila TN                                 Vantaa            92           116                   ETE  Pääkaupunkiseutu               598           Tikkurila                            0                                       P5                               P5             1               90            2                2                  0         40                                                       -1     00:00                                                                                                                                                                                  0000-00-00 00:00:00              00:00:00             0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1682855815
```

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't unfortunately the solution to my problem. My goal is to extract the dates of the coming matches and this code gives me only some matches from the last year.

Comment: @LeeviOksanen This will give you all 541 matches (just print all dataframe `print(df)`). The last match has date `2023-10-01`

Comment: Thank you! Now I can start to figure out how to move this data to a CSV file or something similar. Can I ask how you found the api_url you are using?

Comment: @LeeviOksanen To save the file as csv use `df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)`. I found the URL in Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab.

Comment: Another question: when I save the file as csv and open it up, it has only one row, which makes it difficult to read and analyze. How do I save it with multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

Stop guessing and inspect the HTML you're getting in your Python code. If we start with:

```
fixtures = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="scrolldiv"]/main/div', first=True)
```

And then print out the HTML contained in that element:

```
print(fixtures.html[:100])
```

You'll see that even though your browser shows an `<aside>` element in the DOM, there is no such element in the HTML you've retrieved in the Python code. That's why your xpath expression is returning `None`; you're asking for an element that doesn't exist.

---

In fact, you probably want to write the contents of `r.html.html` to a file and inspect it; you may find that it does not contain the content that you expect.

When I perform that check, I discovered that the retrieved HTML does **not** contain the expected table, and instead has a cookie warning ("Suomen Palloliiton verkkosivustot käyttävät evästeitä..."); presumably the table only shows up after acknowledging the cookie warning.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what I should do to get the expected table?